# Flash CS6 - What is Best Practices for Where to Put a Document Class?

Tags: flash-cs5, flash-cs6, flash-ide

Suppose you are given a folder with these 5 things in it:

folder: bin

folder: src

folder: lib

folder obj

ProjectName.as3proj

I am right now just creating a .fla called ProjectNameShell.fla that is basically an empty file. I just use it to publish through CS6 and also state which class to start from. Is the standard place to put this fla in this first folder or in src?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this when I got fed up with Flash Builder and switched to coding in Sublime Text 2 and published using Flash CS5.5.

You want to place the ProjectNameShell.fla in the same folder as the main document class that you point to in that file.  Also, if there are any external classes that you require in your code make sure to add the class paths to these files using the ActionScript 3.0 Settings in Flash preferences.

Comment: Hey, I am actually using Sublime Text 2, too! I was having problems actually when I had ProjectNameShell.fla in a folder src. The document Class, say Document.as was in a folder called game in a folder called mysite in a folder called com, I though that Flash Pro would be fine if I entered com.mysite.game.Document , but I doesnt seem to find the classes at all...

Comment: As long as you place the FLA inside the game folder (the same folder as Document.as), you can set the Class: in the properties panel to "Document". That way you don't need the full path name there.  As I mentioned earlier though, if your source code requires or "imports" other actionscript classes, you need to tell Flash where those are located using the ActionScript 3.0 Settings window in Flash's preferences.  Without those class paths in place Flash won't know where to look to compile your code properly.